# Google App Engine: import export blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Using appcfg.py it's quite easy to import export the datastore.

But what about the blobstore?
Is there any similar way to import/export the blobstore? If not are they some libraries to do so?

The goal is to move the blobstore from an Appengine app to another Appengine app

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bulkloader doesn't currently support uploading or downloading blobs. In order to do this, you'd have to write your own code for it.

Comment: "doesn't currently", does it mean it will?

Comment: @brillout.com We don't have immediate plans to add it, but it's likely we will, yes.

Comment: Any news on this feature @NickJohnson?

Comment: @filias I no longer work on App Engine, so I'm the wrong person to ask. :)